# A ratio of Amperean and Maxwell terms for an AC wire

Tags: magnetic-fields

I have carefully gone through entire textbook by Purcell and Morin, a few articles, and other rather introductory sources, yet still struggle with understanding fundamentals and feel I comprehend little in electromagnetism; but I am sure I am not alone in this. Anyway, here's the problem and the way I have solved it:

My goal is to estimate the error in calculations of magnetic field away from a straight wire based solely on Ampere's law and depending on frequency.

We assume $I = I_0 \cos(\omega t)$. The point of reference is then the simplification $B = \mu_0 I / 2 \pi R$, correct for static cases. And my method is to make a ratio of $B$ calculated on the basis of Maxwell equations to this term. The ratio is assumed to give an approximation of the error in question.

First, I calculated the electric field induced by changing magnetic field based on the problem 3.8 in D.Fleisch's Student's guide to Maxwell's equations ([link](http://www.danfleisch.com/maxwell/chapter3/problem8)). This way I got:

Sorry, I am writinhg this on ipad and it is extremely hardto type a mathematical expressions here also impossible to insert a screen shot from my notes with calculations and telling drawing, but I should be able to edit this post later, as for now I give up

Hopefully you get the idea of my solution - I use first the Faraday-Maxwell law with integration over a square, then Ampere-Maxwell law with an integration over a square of the same length sides. Both integrations take care of E and B varying with distance. At the end I do the ratio mentioned and express it in terms of frequency.

The goal of this post is to ask the community if this is a right way to tackle this problem. Or if there are better ways, invoke them and instigate a discussion on more complicated cases of AC wires or physical factors which could be taken into consideration in calculations.

Comment: *I am writinhg this on ipad and it is extremely hardto type a mathematical expressions here.* I write most of my answers on an iPad and find it very easy to write MathJax. Do you understand that it only involves standard ASCII characters?

Comment: *impossible to insert a screen shot from my notes with calculations* Please do *not* post an image of calculations. You are expected to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for all math.

Comment: I am sorry but I can paste only a drawing, I do not know this tool you are refering to and it would take me ages to write down the whole thing in this way here. If a picture is ok with you I can proceed, otherwise I need to abort.

Comment: Ps. If you so insist on this math typing, you might find useful having a look at symbolab apps - they use graphical, extremely user-friendly way of electronic writing math formulas. I believe similar tools exists already for web implementations as well, just ready to be installed as modules for some software of websites.

Comment: *I do not know this tool you are refering to.* I provided a link to a tutorial.

Comment: And I was about to provide my solution but you interrupted me.

Comment: Is there anything in the terms and conditions of this forum which would explicitly prohibit the use of screenshots of calculations instead of typed calculations?

Comment: No. This is not a legal requirement. It is part if the standards that this community has established. There are at least three reasons why images of text and math are strongly discouraged. 1. They are not accessible to visually-impaired members. 2. They are not searchable or indexable. 3. They disrupt the visually uniformity of the site. The purpose of the site is not merely to answer a question for the person posting, but to build a physics Q&A repository for future readers.

Comment: So I respectfully ask that you comply with the expectations that apply to everyone posting here. Thanks again.

Comment: Is Better contribution in graphical form or no contribution at all? Besides, I believe it is overwhelmingly Qualitative expressions that are indexed and searched by people and search engines, not math formulas. Hence posting a graphic doesn't change much. Above all, this is not just about answering my question, far from it; looks like you get it all wrong and underappreciate people.